# Cancelling my current valid visa to apply for a new Schengen visa as my current one expires mid-trip

Tags: schengen, visa-expiration, visa-cancellation, schengen-visas

I have a current Schengen visa until the 8th of September, however I'm planning to go to Greece until the 11th. It's literally a matter of days, but I still need a new visa.

The Greek Consulate has advised me that I cannot apply for a new one while I still hold a valid one. The Swiss Embassy (who issued my current one) has informed me the same, and said that I can 'repeal' my current one. (Not sure if this is the same as "cancelling" or 'revoking' my visa). The Greek Consulate however, has said that this would look bad for me in future applications (apparently it will not mention WHY my visa was cancelled) and have suggested that I overstay my visa rather and just pay the fine. That, however, is not an option for me, as I travel to Europe often and would rather not stay in a country illegally and risk being blacklisted for future trips.

Does anyone have any advice? I really feel like I am being forced to illegally overstay my welcome or change my flights. All I want to do is apply for a new one in the correct and legal manner.

Comment: I think you've got both extremes of the advice from the Greeks and the Swiss. It's up to you to choose what works best for you with the other alternatives being either you don't go, or you fit the trip within the visa validity of the current visa.

Comment: The Greek consulate could issue a visa valid for three days.  Did you ask about that?  Also, they're wrong about forbidding you to apply before the expiration of your ccurrent visa; the visa code explicitly allows this in the case of a multiple-entry visa.